# CSS Image Background Position

Tags: html, css

I want a layout like this. Please take a look the image

[image]

As you can see, i have top bar and footer bar. Since footer bar is solid bar, i can just use div and fill the solid color.

But for the top bar, I have to use image as an background inside div. And here is the image of top bar.

[image]

What I want to do is, the black square box (logo) should be fixed at the right corner and the bar should repeat according to the width of the screen.

Please kindly provide me the css for the top bar. Thank you.

Edit: Sorry about my careless. Here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px">
<div style="width:100%; height:100%">
<div style="position:absolute; top:10px; background:url(bglogo.png); width:100%; height:100px"></div>
<div style="position:absolute; bottom:0px; width:100%; height:20px; background:#000"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please kindly post some code that you've tried so that we can help you work through it, rather than expecting us to do your work for you.

Comment: sorry about that, i just added my code.

Comment: My answer hasn't changed since you've posted your code - besides the fact that you should add a doctype (such as `<!DOCTYPE html>`) as the very first line.

Comment: thanks, i just wrote it quick, that's why i didn't declare any. Please kindly check your answer, i just commented back. Please help me for the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an image for the entire top bar. Handle it in exactly the same way as the bottom bar, but with a few additions.

You should do it as I'm suggesting because the logo should be a clickable link.

The HTML should be similar to this:

```
<div id="topBar">
    <a id="logo" href="/"><img src="logo.png" alt="whatever" /></a>
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
#topBar {
    position: relative;
}
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    right: 0
}
```

Comment: the reason that I used image for the top bar is because, as you can see, after square box (logo), there's no bar anymore. The bar ends when it hits to the logo, so let's say if we are using bar and over lapped the logo square box with z-index, at the right side, there will be still a bar because 100%. I hope you will understanding what i am saying. Sorry about my bad english

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? http://jsbin.com/uleqes (note that you can change `110` to `100` to make it touch)

Comment: ah no, what i am trying to tell is, i don't want to be like this, http://imm.io/7Xbe if i use html instead of background image. Beside right side of the square box, I want some space. If i use html bar, it will become like the sample image that i just show you. I want no bar beside of the square box.

Answer (score 0):

To put your black square box you can use absolute position inside a relative position tag. To put exact pixel placement and set z-index to decide whats in front.

You can also use class for box with negative margin to put on ligne.

Comment: the reason that I used image for the top bar is because, as you can see, after square box (logo), there's no bar anymore. The bar ends when it hits to the logo, so let's say if we are using bar and over lapped the logo square box with z-index, at the right side, there will be still a bar because 100%. I hope you will understanding what i am saying. Sorry about my bad english